# Folder creation in Control-M through PowerShell/Windows creates a file instead of a folder

Tags: powershell, control-m

I am using PowerShell and BMC Control-M for automation, I have created a PowerShell script to create a folder:

```
$directoryname= "D:\sysdba" 
$DoesFolderExist = Test-Path $directoryname 
$null = if (!$DoesFolderExist){MKDIR "$directoryname"}

$directoryname= "D:\temp" 
$DoesFolderExist = Test-Path $directoryname 
$null = if (!$DoesFolderExist){MKDIR "$directoryname"}
```

I am using below command to create folder on host server:

```
<commands>
  <command>\\Path\SPUpgrade\Create_Folder.ps1</command>
</commands>
```

But it is creating a file instead of folder:

[image]

Any idea why? I am confused as why not creating folder and why file

Comment: No clue why mkdir doesn't work anymore but you could try to replace it with: `new-item -Path $directoryname -ItemType Directory`

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour with your code. Can you confirm that it is really your script producing the `sysdba` file and not some other process that runs at the same time? You can test this by changing the path from 'D:\sysdba' to 'D:\foo' and see if the same happens.

Comment: It could be an alias? try md or suggestions provided here.

Comment: i checked new-itemtype directory same file is getting generated instead of folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `mkdir` from Powershell is not encouraged since `mkdir` is an external utility and not an internal Powershell command. Instead, use `New-Item -ItemType directory` to achieve what you want:

```
$directoryname= "D:\sysdba" 
if(!(Test-Path -Path $directoryname )){
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryname
    Write-Host "created a new folder"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "The folder is already exists"
}
```

And you can do the same for "D:\temp".

Comment: i checked again file got generated